# webservices - wsimport hangs on parsing WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

These are my environment variables:

System variables:
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\

Path:
...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;...

I key the following in the command line:

> c:\wsimport>wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL -Xdebug

I receive the following message

> [DEBUG] Authorization file "C:\Users\myPC.metro\auth" not found. If
>   the WSDL access needs Basic Authentication, please provide
>   authorization file with read access at C:\Users\myPC.metro\auth or
>   use -Xauthfile to give the authorization file and on each line
>   provide authorization information using this format : http[s]://user:password@host:port//
>
> parsing WSDL...

Where my configuration is incorrect?

Comment: are you using a proxy server?

Comment: @BevynQ - no proxies... I am just puzzled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what happened but it's working now. It seems like my issue was perhaps related to my internet connection. I was online but the connection was pretty slow. Now everything's back to normal and my wsimport command is working.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...I am getting the same problem but it is not resolving - I checked my connection to the server that contains the WSDL and a wget works for it.  However, wsimport is still stuck on "parsing WSDL..."  I've also tried copying the WSDL files locally and using them instead, but it is still stuck on "parsing WSDL"

Comment: OK - It took a while but I got a 504 (gateway timeout error) - when I copied the WSDL files locally and pointed to them, I forgot to also change the XSD imports from the network to local, hence even though I had the WSDLs locally, wsimport was still trying to get the XSDs from the network and timing out.